# Why does truncating a BytesIO mess it up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytesio

Running this on Python 3.5.1 on OSX:

```
import io

b = io.BytesIO()

b.write(b'222')
print(b.getvalue())

b.truncate(0)
b.write(b'222')
print(b.getvalue())
```

Produces:

```
b'222'
b'\x00\x00\x00222'
```

So truncating the `BytesIO` somehow causes it to start inserting extra zero bytes in the beginning? Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`truncate` does not move the file pointer. So the next byte is written to the next position. You have also to seek to the beginning:

```
b.seek(0)
b.truncate()
```

Comment: Relevant docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate). Note that it reads also "(on most systems, additional bytes are zero-filled)"